# How to say "Pretty women are not necessarily attractive, let alone ugly women"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I want to say the following

> Pretty women are not necessarily attractive, let alone ugly women.

in Japanese. My attempt is as follows.

> 不美人どころか、美人も魅力的だとは限らない。

Is it correct and natural?

Comment: I don't completely understand the original English sentence. Can you clarify?

Comment: The original sentence isn't really something anyone would say in English in the first place, honestly.

Comment: Someone might say something like "Just because someone's pretty doesn't mean they're attractive" in English, but I can't figure out how to work the "let alone" part into the sentence.

Comment: "Even a beautiful woman is not necessarily attractive to me, let alone an ugly one." - is my attempt to preserve the original as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say,

> 美人であったとしても魅力的だとは限らない。[醜]{みにく}いならなおさらである。

I don't think the word 「不美人」 is commonly used. For 'Ugly', '[醜]{みにく}い' or 'ブス' in an informal context would be more natural.

My Japanese expression above sounds to conclude that 
'An ugly person is not attractive.'
If the conclusion you want to deliver is 'Being pretty is not enough to make oneself attractive.', then you would say

> 醜い人が魅力的ではないのは確かだが、美人だからといって魅力的だとは限らない。